# Powershell Get MST Info

Tags: powershell, windows-installer

I have to read some Information out of an MSI with an applied MST. I know how to read the tables from a pure MSI but don't know how to apply an MST.

I used this for MSI:

```
    Process {
    try {
        # Read property from MSI database
        $WindowsInstaller = New-Object -ComObject WindowsInstaller.Installer
        $MSIDatabase = $WindowsInstaller.GetType().InvokeMember("OpenDatabase", "InvokeMethod", $null, $WindowsInstaller, @($Path.FullName, 0))
        $Query = "SELECT Value FROM Property WHERE Property = '$($Property)'"
        # $Query = "SELECT Action FROM CustomAction WHERE Action = '$($CustomAction)'"
        $View = $MSIDatabase.GetType().InvokeMember("OpenView", "InvokeMethod", $null, $MSIDatabase, ($Query))
        $View.GetType().InvokeMember("Execute", "InvokeMethod", $null, $View, $null) | out-null
        $Record = $View.GetType().InvokeMember("Fetch", "InvokeMethod", $null, $View, $null)
        try {
            $Value = $Record.GetType().InvokeMember("StringData", "GetProperty", $null, $Record, 1)

            # Commit database and close view
            $MSIDatabase.GetType().InvokeMember("Commit", "InvokeMethod", $null, $MSIDatabase, $null) | out-null
            $View.GetType().InvokeMember("Close", "InvokeMethod", $null, $View, $null) | Out-Null
            $MSIDatabase = $null
            $View = $null
        } catch {
            $Value = "-"
        }
        # Return the value

        return $Value
```

If someone can help me it would be really nice!

Thanks, Moritz :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the example from the Win SDK "wilstxfm.vbs". On my system it's installed at this path:

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x64\wilstxfm.vbs
```

Can't paste the code here because of copyright issue, but they basically do this:

```
database = installer.OpenDatabase(msiPath,0) 
database.ApplyTransform(mstPath, iteViewTransform + iteAddExistingRow + iteDelNonExistingRow + iteAddExistingTable + iteDelNonExistingTable + iteUpdNonExistingRow + iteChangeCodePage)
view = database.OpenView("SELECT * FROM `_TransformView` ORDER BY `Table`, `Row`")
```

Then they iterate over the records of the view to print the changes that the transform would do.

You should be able to translate that .vbs sample into PowerShell code or simply call the .vbs script from PS.